# How to add back icon with hamburger menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hamburger-menu

I am developing an app which needs a requirement to show a back icon with a hamburger icon and a back icon as well as shown in the below image.

[image]

How should I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there's any provision to do that out of the box, you should try creating a customized toolbar, that way you can add any view in your toolbar.

Comment: according to material design, this should not be done.

Comment: You can use back button with custom toolbar in next screen or detail screen not in main screen as per suggested google material guide line.

Comment: negative voters could you please help me with reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using custom toolbar like bellow

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mImgBack"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mImgHamburger"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mImgHamburger"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now after that set toolbar to your

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.profileToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and perform the action and click on your image view as you want

Comment: I tried this it is working but the problem is that when I am setting the title it is showing before the icons. How should we change this?

Comment: Then put text view behind those icons and set the title in that text view and don't set default title using like setTitle()

Answer (score 1):

The only solution for this is to creating a custom toolbar where you have to place these two icons (back button and hamburg menu icon) manually and implement the drawer functionality at run time.

It means you have to implement back button and hamburg menu button functionality individually.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the solution you are looking for, but if you implement a custom toolbar (like mentioned by others as well), you can use an ImageView with DrawerArrowDrawable.

You can then transform the icon from hambruger to arrow back and forth programmatically, without having to handle multiple views.

You can initialize the DrawerArrowDrawable like so:

```
homeDrawable = DrawerArrowDrawable(context)
homeDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
homeDrawable.setBarThickness(dimen(R.dimen.toolbar_home_bars_thickness).toFloat())
homeDrawable.setBarLength(dimen(R.dimen.toolbar_home_bars_length).toFloat())
homeDrawable.setGapSize(dimen(R.dimen.toolbar_home_bars_gap).toFloat())
homeDrawable.setArrowShaftLength(dimen(R.dimen.toolbar_home_arrow_shaft_length).toFloat())
homeDrawable.setArrowHeadLength(dimen(R.dimen.toolbar_home_arrow_head_length).toFloat())
```

Then set it as a background for your imageview:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(homeDrawable)
```

You can toggle the icon with a simple animation (ValueAnimator) like this:

```
private fun toggleDrawerIcon(show: Boolean) {
    val currentProgress = homeDrawable.progress
    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(currentProgress, if (show) 0.0F else 1.0F)
    animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
        var value = valueAnimator.animatedValue
        if (value is Float)
            homeDrawable?.progress = value
    }
    animator.duration = 200
    animator.start()
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to decide the current state of the icon whenever it is tapped to make sure it will perform the desired action.